# monorestore issue BadValue: object to insert exceeds cappedMaxSize

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I use Meteor with WireTiger 3.2.12

I've made dump using monogdump
When I'm trying to restore it, on some documents I recieved this:

> error: write to oplog failed: BadValue: object to insert exceeds
>   cappedMaxSize

This collection is not 'Capped' (I tested it with db.my_collection_name.stats()["capped"])

How it's possible to import such documents?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to insert an object with recursive properties (one of objects was self referencing).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the collection was previously created as capped and it still has the property attached to it.
Check the collection properties, or (if you don't need the data, drop it and re-create it)